Pollution-themed animated TV-series that aired in the early '90s?
I watched this show as a child in North America in the early '90s, though it is probably older, and have nothing but vague memories with which to identify it. Thus, anything fitting even one of the criteria is a likely candidate and would be a helpful clue! (It's also possible that I've somehow combined multiple shows in my head.)
Here are the details I remember:

Main setting: under water (magical?) kingdom
Protagonists: small, colorful-haired creatures reminiscent of Trolls (though probably better-looking)  One of these was a "Princess" (who may or may not have had blue hair)
Antagonists: a woman and her two male cronies on a ship; the woman was likely dark haired, tall and thin; one man was tall, the other was short, neither one very bright
There was also some theme of pollution, i.e. dumping garbage/oil into the water, smoke into the air

This probably isn't much to go on, which is why my previous searches have been fruitless, but any help would be much appreciated!

SMOGGIES!
I couldn't remember it either, and searched all over, coming up with nothing. Then my bf had a brainwave and figured it out. You can find the theme song on Youtube.

Mind explaining why you think this is the answer?

YES! That's it! Thank you!!! From Wikipedia: "The Smoggies was a Canadian animated children's television show by Cinar that began airing in 1988. In the United States, the show was aired under the name Stop the Smoggies in 1994 on HBO,[1] and in France, as SOS Polluards.[2] In the French part of Canada, it was aired under the name Touftoufs et Polluards. The show was broadcast in Ireland under its original Canadian title."

@shp could you please edit in some of the info from Dani's comment?

This sounds a bit like Pirates of Dark Water. 


 
The show isn't set underwater but it is set in a world that only has islands for land. Also it has a mysterious pollution called Dark Water that kills and destroys anything it touches. There is a prince and the is a villain racing him to collect treasures that can defeat dark water. The villain has two idiots in his crew of pirates.  

This fits almost all the criteria and is a really good guess! Unfortunately it's not the answer I was looking for, but maybe it will answer someone else's question :) +1

You're not thinking of Snorks are you?


It's definitely possible. However, I watched the intro and it doesn't ring any bells. There still seems to be a missing piece to this puzzle. Hopefully we can find it!
